# Kafka: local producer cannot send or receive messages

Tags: apache-kafka, google-compute-engine, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to use google cloud compute engine VM instance as kafka consumer. I found out that the VM blocks traffic from any external computer and I successfully setup firewall rules to access the VM from my local machine.

I'm able to create and list topics on the cloud VM instance. But I'm Unable to send and receive messages to and from kafka topics. 
It throws timeout exception.

I used telnet to check if the port was open and I obtained an Escape sequence for the port as well (9092).

When I try to achieve the same thing using another cloud VM instance, I'm able to do all kafka operations. (send/receive messages, create/list topics)

So far, I've only tried to use the kafka console producer and console consumer.

I've been trying to solve this from the last week. It would be of a great help if someone could help me out.

I'm running both kafka server and consumer on a single Cloud VM. I wanted to use Raspberry Pi as Producer.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

My config/server.properties file is as below

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().

advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://35.196.XXX.XXX:9092 #Google VM External IP

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma seperated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to exceessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

And when I run the following command on My local machine

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 35.196.227.191:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

I'm getting the following error on my Google VM instance:

```
[2018-02-04 12:42:19,839] ERROR [KafkaApi-0] Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the required replication factor '1' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
```

But when I see the logs when server was started,

```
[2018-02-04 12:33:39,995] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Removed 0 expired offsets in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2018-02-04 12:33:40,012] INFO [ProducerId Manager 0]: Acquired new producerId block (brokerId:0,blockStartProducerId:1000,blockEndProducerId:1999) by writing to Zk with path version 2 (kafka.coordinator.transaction.ProducerIdManager)
[2018-02-04 12:33:40,081] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=0] Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2018-02-04 12:33:40,095] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=0] Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
[2018-02-04 12:33:40,099] INFO [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 0]: Starting (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMarkerChannelManager)
[2018-02-04 12:33:40,249] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/0 (is it secure? false) (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2018-02-04 12:33:40,268] INFO Result of znode creation is: OK (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
---> [2018-02-04 12:33:40,270] INFO Registered broker 0 at path /brokers/ids/0 with addresses: EndPoint(35.196.XXX.XXX,9092,ListenerName(PLAINTEXT),PLAINTEXT) (kafka.utils.ZkUtils)
[2018-02-04 12:33:40,282] INFO Kafka version : 1.0.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2018-02-04 12:33:40,282] INFO Kafka commitId : aaa7af6d4a11b29d (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2018-02-04 12:33:40,286] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

When I see the **line --->**(check logs above), It says that the broker was registered. Can someone explain what is happening.

Comment: Have you configured advertised listeners correctly?

Comment: I have assigned the VM's external IP as the advertised listener PLAINTEXT://IP:9092

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of potential issues.

1. The bootstrap-server ip you provide is used for the initial connection, but afterwards the **advertised.host.name** property is used to connect to a broker. If your **advertised.host.name** is not resolvable by your consumer then he will not be able to connect to a broker even though you provided a perfectly accessible bootstrap-service ip and port. So update the **advertised.host.name** config to be your broker's ip.
2. Some consumers have to directly connect to zookeeper to discover brokers and lookup partition offsets. Make sure your zookeeper port is open (usually 2181 I think) and accessible from your local machine.